# Best threading queue example / best practice

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have data that needs to be executed on a certain background thread.  I have code coming from all other threads that need to call into this.  does anyone have a good tutorial or best practice on having a queue for synchronization to support this threading requirement

Comment: See [StackOverflow: How to work threading with ConcurrentQueue(T)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4551087/199364) and maybe  [Code Review: Simple generic multithreaded queue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/12053/simple-generic-multithreaded-queue).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could either:

- implement a [producer/consumer model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy12yx1f.aspx) (which use not thread-safe [generic queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx))
- or use in your background thread a [synchronized queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.queue.synchronized.aspx), which does comment on the process of Enumerating through a collection.

Comment: The code sample in the [first link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy12yx1f.aspx) is not recommended as it has a possible race condition resulting in lost signals.  Don't use it!

Answer (score 35):

Check out [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/), by Joseph Albahari, very complete reference about multithreading. In particular, he covers [producer/consumer queues](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_ProducerConsumerQWaitHandle).

Comment: Your threading link to Albahari is a very great resource.

Answer (score 5):

This is an interesting article on ThreadPools:

> http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/smartthreadpool.aspx

For simpler use cases you could also use .Net's own ThreadPool class.

Answer (score 1):

One of my favorite solutions to this problem is similar to the `producer/consumer` pattern.

I create a master thread (pretty much my program's `Main()`) which holds a blocking queue object.

This master thread spins off several worker threads which simple pop things off the central blocking thread and process them. Since it's a threadsafe  blocking queue, the synchronization bits are easy--the `TaskQueue.Dequeue()` call will block until a task is enqueued by the producer/main thread.

You can dynamically manage the number of workers you want or fix it according to a configuration variable--since they're all just popping things off the queue, the number of workers doesn't add any complexity.

In my case, I have a service which processes several different types of `tasks`. I have the queue typed to handle something generic like `TaskQueueTask`. Then I subclass that and override the `Execute()` method.

---

I've also tried the .NET threadpool approach where in you can throw things into the pool very easily. It was extremely simple to use but also provided little control, and no guarantee of execution order, timing, etc. It's recommended only for light-weight tasks.

Comment: Here's a blocking queue: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20060414.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution. It shows you how to implement the producer-consumer pattern. Has also some explanation on what can be done with it. Like different combinations of the number of producers and consumers.

http://devpinoy.org/blogs/jakelite/archive/2009/01/12/threading-patterns-the-producer-consumer-pattern.aspx

http://devpinoy.org/blogs/jakelite/archive/2009/02/03/threading-patterns-producer-consumer-pattern-examples.aspx

Comment: both of links are invalid now.