# Schedule tasks in order

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, scheduled-tasks, c#-5.0

I have tasks as below:

1. Task taskInput to get data to inputQueue
2. Task taskOutput to grab data from inputQueue to outputQueue
3. Parallel tasks for consuming data from outputQueue

I want to run the tasks with the condition:

> Run taskInput first, taskOutput , finally Consumer.

The corresponding code:

```
            // Get data to inputQueue
            Task taskInput = new Task(()=>AddingItemToInputQueue());
            taskInput.Start();  
            // Grab data from inputQueue to outputQueue.
            Task taskOutput = new Task(() => AddItemToOutputQueue());
            taskOutput.Start();

            // Parallel tasks for consume data from outputQueue
            int threadCount = n;
            Task[] workers = new Task[threadCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
            {
                Task task=Task.Run(()=>Consumer(i));
                workers[i] = task;
            }
            Task.WaitAll(workers);
```

About inputQueue and outputQueue:

```
    BlockingCollection<Messages> InputQueue = new BlockingCollection<Messages>();
    BlockingCollection<Messages> OutputQueue = new BlockingCollection<Messages>();
```

My questions:

1. Schedule the tasks. I thought we could use Task.ContinueWith Method bot not sure how to apply it to `Consumer`.
2. I am not sure whether it is thread safe because the new items may be added to the inputQueue while running the `Consumer`.

Comment: Do you use `taskInput` and `taskOutput` after the Start?

Comment: I am not sure your meaning but Consumer will use the data from outputQueue. The data in outputQueue is from taskOutut.

Comment: I meant if you use the `taskInput` and `taskOutput` objects after you start them. Or you start and do nothig with these objects

Comment: I start and do nothing with these objects.

Comment: Is this a `C# 4.0` question or a `C# 5.0` question? It looks like a `C# 5.0` question because you are using `Task.Run`. In that case, don't use the `Task` constructor, just use `Task.Run`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try starting the first Task (`taskInput`) and when it's finished, continue with the second Task (`taskOutput`), unless it's necessary to work in parallel. In this case, you have to start both separately, as you're already doing.

```
Task.Run(() => AddingItemToInputQueue())
            .ContinueWith(task => AddItemToOutputQueue());
```

And in parallel, start Tasks for consume data from `outputQueue`

```
// Parallel tasks for consume data from outputQueue
int threadCount = n;
Task[] workers = new Task[threadCount];
for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
{
    Task task = Task.Run(() => Consumer(i));
    workers[i] = task;
}
Task.WaitAll(workers);
```

Or you could try somehing like this:

```
Task.Run(() => AddingItemToInputQueue())
    .ContinueWith(x => AddItemToOutputQueue())
    .ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        int threadCount = n;
        Task[] workers = new Task[threadCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
        {
            Task task = Task.Run(() => Consumer(i));
            workers[i] = task;
        }
        Task.WaitAll(workers);
    });
```

In this case, it will run as you want: first `taskInput`, then `taskOutput` and finally `Consumer`.

[BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is thread-safe, so you can add and remove data in multi-tasks, it will manage itself blocking when is necessary.

You can check more about `Task.Factory.StartNew` and `Task.Run` [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)

Comment: Can we replace Task.Factory.StartNew with Task.Run? I heard that using Task.Factory.StartNew is dangerous.

Comment: Yes, actually this is the best approach. You can check more about it here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx

Comment: Attention: this will block the UI if called from a UI thread because of `Task.WaitAll`. In that case, just await on `Task.WhenAll` instead.

Answer (score 0):

With `async-await` you can write it like this:

```
async Task DoStuffAsync()
{
    // Get data to inputQueue
    await Task.Run(()=>AddingItemToInputQueue());

    // Grab data from inputQueue to outputQueue.
    await Task.Run(() => AddItemToOutputQueue());

    // Parallel tasks for consume data from outputQueue
    int threadCount = n;
    Task[] workers = new Task[threadCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
    {
        Task task=Task.Run(()=>Consumer(i));
        workers[i] = task;
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(workers);
}
```

But since you need to wrap your `AddingItemToInputQueue` and `AddItemToOutputQueue` with `Task`s to make them asynchronous, you are just adding overhead. The same goes to `Consumer`.

You might as well do it like this:

```
void DoStuff()
{
    // Get data to inputQueue
    AddingItemToInputQueue();

    // Grab data from inputQueue to outputQueue.
    AddItemToOutputQueue();

    // Parallel tasks for consume data from outputQueue
    int threadCount = n;
    Parallel.For(0, n, i => Consumer(i));
}
```

Comment: --@Paulo: I am not sure if Parallel is thread-safe, when iterating Consumer, the new items may be added to the OutputQueue. Could have throw an exception?

Comment: I don't understand your point. It's not `Parallel` that needs to be thread safe. It's `Compute` or the queue that need to be thread safe. Aren't the items supposed to be all in the queue after the call to `AddItemToOutputQueue`?

Comment: --@Paulo, I had a similar poster, please see the comment by @Servy at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688679/process-queue-with-multithreading-or-tasks