# Do I need two queues for producer-consumer pattern?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I have a difficult time to understand the `BlockingCollection`.
The following code is from an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688679/process-queue-with-multithreading-or-tasks) but it used two queues.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().run();
        }

        void run()
        {
            int threadCount = 4;
            Task[] workers = new Task[threadCount];

            Task.Factory.StartNew(consumer);

            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
            {
                int workerId = i;
                Task task = new Task(() => worker(workerId));
                workers[i] = task;
                task.Start();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Queueing work item {0}", i);
                inputQueue.Add(i);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Stopping adding.");
            inputQueue.CompleteAdding();
            Task.WaitAll(workers);
            outputQueue.CompleteAdding();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");

            Console.ReadLine();
         }

         void worker(int workerId)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is starting.", workerId);

            foreach (var workItem in inputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is processing item {1}", workerId, workItem);
                Thread.Sleep(100);          // Simulate work.
                outputQueue.Add(workItem);  // Output completed item.
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is stopping.", workerId);
        }

        void consumer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Consumer is starting.");

            foreach (var workItem in outputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Consumer is using item {0}", workItem);
                Thread.Sleep(25);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Consumer is finished.");
        }

            BlockingCollection<int> inputQueue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
            BlockingCollection<int> outputQueue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
       }
    }
```

Can I just use one queue? If using .net 4.5(TPL) to replace it, what can I do?

Comment: Link to that old answer. But in general, P/C only requires 1 queue.

Comment: This already uses TPL. And  Concurrent Collections.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I added the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Producer-consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem) is a model that defines two actors:

1. One who creates items - producer
2. One who processes those items - consumer

There are different ways to organize their interoperation, but the most simple one is Queue - producer enqueues new items to it, consumer dequeues them.

The code example shown above actually contains three actors and two queues:

1. Producer 1 (in Main)

   ```
       for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Queueing work item {0}", i);
           inputQueue.Add(i);
           Thread.Sleep(50);
       }
   ```
2. Consumer 1 and Producer 2 at the same time ( worker method):

   ```
       foreach (var workItem in inputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is processing item {1}", workerId, workItem);
           Thread.Sleep(100);          // Simulate work.
           outputQueue.Add(workItem);  // Output completed item.
       }
   ```
3. Consumer 2 (consumer method):

   ```
       foreach (var workItem in outputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Consumer is using item {0}", workItem);
           Thread.Sleep(25);
       }
   ```

This is not producer-consumer - it is Conveyor "pattern" organized upon two sequentially connected producer-consumer systems.

**So, the ANSWER:**

No, there is no need to use two queues. You can reduce the example to proper one-level producer-consumer just removing the `worker` method and operating in the `consumer` method upon inputQueue.

**ABOUT THE [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688679/process-queue-with-multithreading-or-tasks):**

The old question does not deal with producer-consumer - it deals with conveyor model - data flow. Simple producer-consumer does not need any complex multilevel data transitions.