# Can't add items to the collection in the second round

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, blockingcollection

Basically I have a blockingcollection in my windows service application, each time I want to add 4 items to the collection then processing it.

The first round is okay, but the second round failed.
The error is

> The BlockingCollection has been marked as complete with regards to additions.

My code:

```
    public static BlockingCollection<Tuple<ChannelResource, string>> bc = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<ChannelResource, string>>();
    public static List<string> list = new List<string>(); // then add 100 items to it.
```

The main application code:

```
            ProcessCall pc = new ProcessCall(OvrTelephonyServer, bc);
            while (true)
            {
                ThreadEvent.WaitOne(waitingTime, false);

                lock (SyncVar)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Block begin");
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                    {
                        var firstItem = list.FirstOrDefault();
                        ChannelResource cr = OvrTelephonyServer.GetChannel();
                        bc.TryAdd(Tuple.Create(cr, firstItem));
                        list.Remove(firstItem);
                    }
                    bc.CompleteAdding();
                    pc.SimultaneousCall();
                    Console.WriteLine("Blocking end");
                    if (ThreadState != State.Running) break;
                }
            }
```

I realized that there was a code `bc.CompleteAdding();` to block the further additions. So I commented out it, but it would not go to the second round block. It didn't reach the code `Console.WriteLine("Blocking end");` It was same as my [old thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25169264/not-reach-the-code-as-expected)

Comment: I can see `BlockingCollection` is passed as parameter to `ProcessCall` constructor. Is there any possibility that `ProcessCall` calls `bc.CompleteAdding();`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, perhaps I can. But does it block the second round's additions?

Comment: That depends on when you call `CompleteAdding`. If second iteration runs after `CompleteAdding` called, you'll see this behavior.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, it doesn't work if I move `bc.CompleteAdding();` to ProcessCall. It is same as my old thread. The code doesn't reach `Blocking end` line.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a 'ResetAdding' or whatever, so once you call `CompleteAdding()` you will need to recreate the whole collection.

Comment: @TaW,thanks. I posted my own answer under your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the hint from TaW, I recreated the collection in each iteration.

Each iteration has its own `CompleteAdding()`.

```
                lock (SyncVar)
                {
                    bc = new BlockingCollection<Tuple<ChannelResource, string>>();
                    ProcessCall pc = new ProcessCall(OvrTelephonyServer, bc);
                    if (list.Count > 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Block begin");
                        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                        {
                            if (list.Count > 0)
                            {
                                var firstItem = list.FirstOrDefault();
                                ChannelResource cr = OvrTelephonyServer.GetChannel();
                                bc.TryAdd(Tuple.Create(cr, firstItem));
                                list.Remove(firstItem);
                            }
                        }
                        bc.CompleteAdding();
                        pc.SimultaneousCall();
                        Console.WriteLine("Blocking end");
                    }
                    if (ThreadState != State.Running) break;
                }
```