# How should a waiting system for queued messages be implemented in C#

Tags: c#, queue

I have a service that uses one thread to wait for incoming messages and then puts them into a queue. The frequency of incoming messages vary. They can come frequently or sometimes they get sent in giant batches with longer wait times in between each batch.

Another thread checks the queue and processes the messages if there are any. If there are no messages, then it should wait until a message gets put into the queue. Right now the code for the processing of the messages looks like below.

```
public void Run() {
    while(thereAreNoItemsInQueue) {
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }

    //Start processing messages from queue
}
```

I've heard that using a Sleep within a loop like this is bad practice, so What is the best practice for implementing the wait in this scenario? I've looked into other ways to do the wait, from using AutoResetEvent/ManualResetEvent or using Monitor, but I'm not sure which is best.

- I should also add that the queue these messages are being saved to is a transactional MSMQ

Comment: Blocking collections are your friend.

Answer (score 2):

Not in C#. Never. See:

> They can come frequently or sometimes they get sent in giant batches
>   with longer wait times in between each batch.

Which likely also means processing time fora batch, which says "use persistence".

Windows has a queue mechanism (MSMQ) and you could use a database. But you should not never ever keep work items in process without persistence if you HAVE to work on them. What if the server blue screens?

Dump them into a persistent queue, then work from that.

IF you have to keep them in queue.,... why block a thread? That is wasteful.

When a message comes, create a TASK to process the queue (if none exists). That way a queue without messages is not blocking a thread (which is costly).

For something totaly trivial consider usign tasks with a custom scheduler (to make sure they process max. x at the same time) - voila. It is not like for in process queueing there is not multiple mechanisms in .NET already.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `BlockingCollection` for this.

Here's some sample code (a console app). In this sample, I am using multiple worker threads and one consumer thread, but your code will presumably use just one of each:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().run();
        }

        void run()
        {
            int threadCount = 4;
            Task[] workers = new Task[threadCount];

            Task.Factory.StartNew(consumer);

            for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; ++i)
            {
                int workerId = i;
                Task task = new Task(() => worker(workerId));
                workers[i] = task;
                task.Start();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Queueing work item {0}", i);
                inputQueue.Add(i);
                Thread.Sleep(50);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Stopping adding.");
            inputQueue.CompleteAdding();
            Task.WaitAll(workers);
            outputQueue.CompleteAdding();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        void worker(int workerId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is starting.", workerId);

            foreach (var workItem in inputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is processing item {1}", workerId, workItem);
                Thread.Sleep(100);          // Simulate work.
                outputQueue.Add(workItem);  // Output completed item.
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Worker {0} is stopping.", workerId);
        }

        void consumer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Consumer is starting.");

            foreach (var workItem in outputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Consumer is using item {0}", workItem);
                Thread.Sleep(25);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Consumer is finished.");
        }

        BlockingCollection<int> inputQueue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
        BlockingCollection<int> outputQueue = new BlockingCollection<int>();
    }
}
```

But if you're using `.Net 4.5` you could look into [Dataflow from the the Task Parallel Library (TPL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) (which probably has some better, high-level answers - at the expense of a steeper learning curve, but worth investing the time I think).

Also see [my answer in this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688679/process-queue-with-multithreading-or-tasks) (from which I took the sample code above).