# Checking if a thread is finished fails with IsAlive

Tags: c#, multithreading

In a C# project I have a class (ThreadSpawner) which spawns threads and keeps track of them in a list (_runningJobs). From this list they should be removed if the threads are finished.

So far I tried it with the Thread.IsAlive property but this doesn't work since it seems to be allways true and never becomes false.

What exactly i wanted to check in the IsFinished method is if the thread is already dead and not running anymore which I assumed would happen automatically when the DoJob method is left.

Any hints how to check them?

I don't know which thread state says the thread does not exist anymore...

My (sample) code:

```
  public class ThreadSpawner {

  private List<SpawnedThread> _runningJobs;
  private bool _isStopRequested;
  private int maxRunningJobs = 3;
  private Thread _thread; 
  
  public ThreadSpawner() {
    _runningJobs = new List<SpawnedThread>();
    _isStopRequested = false;
    _thread = null;
  }
  
  public void Start() {
    _thread = new Thread(DoJob);
    _thread.Start();
  }
  
  public void DoJob() {
    while(!_isStopRequested) {

      //check if there are finished jobs in the list and remove them if they are finished
      for (int i = _runningJobs.Count-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (_runningJobs.ElementAt(i).IsFinished()) {
            _runningJobs.RemoveAt(i);
        }
      }

      //spawn threads if possible and required
      if (_runningJobs.Count less maxRunningJobs && ShouldThreadBeSpawned()) {
        SpawnedThread st = new SpawnedThread();
        _runningJobs.Add(st);
        st.Start();
      }

      Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
  }
  
  public void Stop() {
    _isStopRequested = true;

    for (int i = 0; i less _runningJobs.Count; i++) {
      _runningJobs.ElementAt(i).Stop();
    }
  }

  public bool IsFinished() {
    return _thread == null || ( _runningJobs.Count == 0 && _thread.IsAlive);
  }
  
  private bool ShouldThreadBeSpawned() {
    return true; //actually whatever the criteria says
  }
}

public class SpawnedThread {

  private bool _isStopRequested;
  private Thread _thread; 
  
  public ThreadSpawner() {
    _isStopRequested = false;
    _thread = null;
  }
  
  public void Start() {
    _thread = new Thread(DoJob);
    _thread.Start();
  }
  
  public void DoJob() {
    // does whatever it should do
    // and leaves the DoJob method
    // and I assumed when this method is left IsAlive would become false but it doesn't
  }
  
  public void Stop() {
    _isStopRequested = true;
  }

  public bool IsFinished() {
    return _thread == null || _thread.IsAlive;
  }
  
}
```

### Refined question

How do I start Threads/Tasks with the possibility to keep track of the running ones and being able to stop them by code (with the possibilty to call some code for each Thread/Task for stopping contained processes)?

### Some more detail

That whole system is used in a (.NET Core) windows service (see my other questions). The windows service starts the ThreadSpawner. The ThreadSpawner queries a database for jobs to do. For each job it spawns a SpawnedThread. This thread queries another bunch of data from the database, gets some files over network. Then the SpawnedThread starts (one after another) some processes calling executables and passing the results from one executable to the next call of an executable. Then puts resulting files back and stores the results in the database.

Everything works fine except the problem I can't figure out how to tell if a thread is running or not when the windows service is stopped and to kill the spawned thread in a way which also stops the processes. (The same mechanism is also used for checking if a called exe is hanging and kill the hanging exe with its process and SpawnedThread).

### Why I haven't used ThreadPool and ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

First I have. But I were not able to track which threads were running and not able to kill them in way which also stopped the processes. Neither in the case of windows service stop nor in the case that it was detected that an external exe was hanging.

### Why I haven't used tasks

Never worked with them an we (my team) decided we take threads. I am happy to see suggestions how I could do that with tasks.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using Threads and not Tasks? Because Threads are a bad practice, and Tasks are much easier to check against...

Comment: This sounds like a really good candidate for a total rewrite using `Task`s and/or the TPL, where there's built-in support for cancellation and state ([for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688679/)). For starters, maintaining booleans like `_isStopRequested` requires that you study up on memory barriers, to understand why simple assignment won't do. That is not fun.

Comment: You can also use a callback function (let say ThreadCompleted) and invoke this function at the end of thread functionality. and within this function you can write code to remove from your list of running jobs.

Comment: @MIdrees you mean, like Tasks,  with manual callbacks and the overhead of creating a new thread each time

Comment: @monty Even if you don't want to use Tasks for whatever reason, you *shouldn't* use raw threads. Creating a thread has an overhead. All Windows applications can take advantage of preallocated, reusable thread pools. Use [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza(v=vs.110).aspx) to execute a function on a threadpool thread. That's how tasks are executed by default

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I mean at the end of DoJob() method inside SpawnedThread class, an event can be raised, which can be subscribed by ThreadSpawner class, and in this event that particular thread can be removed from running jobs.

Comment: @Markus How did you edit the sample code so the brackets were shown correctly? Always struggling with them

Comment: @gilmishal Never used tasks before. Happy to see how that would work.

Comment: @jeroenMostert Ahm, what? I think I don't understand what you meant?

Comment: @MIdrees Yes, callbacks would be possible but shouldn't there be a way to tell if a thread has to be stopped or not without callbacks? Like a working IsAlive or meaningfull Thread.State?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos added description why I haven't used ThreadPool and QueueUserWorkItem Happy to see suggestions how that would work with ThreadPool

Comment: @monty I've removed the pre and code tags

Comment: @Markus strange, pre and code tags have been the only way since years SO lets me put in formatted code (copy paste from notepad++). Interesting to hear I don't need them. Thx :-)

Comment: @monty the only other thing that's important is to have an indent of 4. You can also use the format code button in the toolbar.

Comment: @monty why do you even care when threads run? You *can't* control it anyway - `Thread.Start` is just a request to the OS. It does *not* start the thread. In fact, the threadpool can give you a thread *faster*. Why do you want to *kill* them? That's (very) bad coding for all threads. Who's going to clean up, dispose of resources? *Signal* them and exit the worker function cooperatively

Comment: @monty you haven't posted any *actual* reason to avoid Tasks or threadpools. You tried to use them in a bad way, a way that would be bad with raw threads as well. Fix your design and use Tasks instead of trying to reinvent them. There are *A LOT* of Windows services that use tasks without any issues. Mine included, which pulls, processes and matches ticket data from IATA, airlines, banks every 15 minutes. I have enough work decrypting and parsing data formats (asynchronously and concurrently). No need to add reinventing tasks to it

Comment: As for suggestions - well, just `Task.Run` will run the worker function just fine. If you want to run something else after it finishes, just write `var result = await Task.Run(...);` and use the result.  Did you try to use `Task.Run` as if it were `Thread.Start` perhaps? With an infinite loop? Don't. Tasks are meant to do *one* thing. If you want to process more things, use more tasks. Or a TPL Dataflow pipeline, to create a pipeline of blocks that run on separate threads (tasks actually) just like PowerShell

Comment: Cancelling and progress reporting from threads are *also* well-described since 2010, with improvements in 2012. Use CancellationToken and `IProgress< T>` either from tasks or raw threads. [Async in 4.5: Enabling Progress and Cancellation in Async APIs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/).

Comment: Finally, make sure you understand what you mean when you say you want to cancel. Cancelling a web or database request won't stop the *server* from processing it. [How do I cancel non-cancelable operations?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think need to change

```
 public bool IsFinished() {
    return _thread == null || _thread.IsAlive;
  }
```

to

```
 public bool IsFinished() {
    return _thread == null || !_thread.IsAlive;
  }
```

Comment: You are soooo genius. In all that complex construct I missed that small detail. It was sooo correct. If I could I would invite you for drink. Kind regards, big thanks and all my love :-)