# How to fire but don't forget in a separate thread using .NET 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I have an issue with converting some code to work asynchronously or in parallel. I am running into an async chain (async/ await traveling up the call stack) that is resulting in my API needing to return a Task to another .NET 4.0 application.

.NET 4.0 cannot implement await so it is forcing a task.Result on the API side which negates the performance improvement.

Within my API, I have some calls to another API(sending notifications), that I do not wish to wait on before returning control back to the caller of my API (slow performance when 3rd party api hangs). I do care about the results of the calls to the 3rd party API for logging purposes.

Using Task.Run to run these calls in parallelism shows a huge difference in UI responsiveness, but I worry about the number of threads this will create and timeout issues within this situation that could deadlock my entire pool.

How can I properly handle this situation in C# .NET 4.5 ?

Can I send all 3rd party API calls from a single context to thread for processing instead of calling task.run on each ?

Comment: Just a FYI, .NET 4.0 can do async/await. You just need to include the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/) NuGet package.

Comment: Thanks Scott. It is not supported for visual studios 2010 (which i am using) but good to know.

Comment: [Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/community/) is totally free for personal use, you might want to consider updating to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a queue to dispatch notifications. When you need to send the notification your API would simply add the notification to the queue and forget it.

Then there you can implement a background task to process the queue. You can configure this background task to use more than one threads if it needs to.

Comment: Do you have any resources I could use to implement this behavior? Specifically, an example of how to add the notifications to a queue and the how I can configure this queue to run in the background. I see many suggestion for the blockingcollection. Any suggestions here?

Comment: Yes, you could use a blocking collection. You could use modified version of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22688679/process-queue-with-multithreading-or-tasks to implement it.

Comment: Would you say my only option is to create and manage my own thread, instead of using the threadpool to queue my tasks? I say this because I need my thread to run in the foreground to ensure the task are handled even after the main thread as ended.

Comment: You don't have to use a thread. You can use the thread pool to process the queue.

Comment: I'm experiencing problems with using the thread pool because once the main thread is closed the worker threads are destroyed. I think the creation and management of my own thread to handle the queue should prevent this premature closure.